# navigation by swipe on mobile phone

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way by theme or plugin where I can navigate from page to page on a mobile using a swipe motion, like gmail on my phone where I can swipe left or right to go to the next email, can that be done for a website - I am using wordpress

Answer (score 0):

I have searched your issue and i found one article.

Here is the link which might be helpful to you : https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/easily-add-touch-gestures-to-your-wordpress-site/?utm_expid=3606929-97.J2zL7V7mQbSNQDPrXwvBgQ.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2F